# Kotlin Multi-Platform - "Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt"

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

When trying to run a main function of a Kotlin JVM module in IntelliJ IDEA using the green triangle next to the function name, I get the following error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt`

Has anyone experienced this before and knows how to fix it? I've tried the suggestions on Google but they seem to not work.

I'm pretty new to Kotlin and Kotlin MultiPlatform as well as Gradle so if you need more details, please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
James.

**EDIT: To clarify, I can run the built .jar file from the command line but cannot run it from inside IntelliJ without this error being produced. If anyone could help so that I can debug the application, I'd be really grateful, I just can't seem to figure it out :)**

Comment: Is the Gradle build successful? IntelliJ IDEA could have tried to run the program even though the compilation failed and no such class was produced. Please try to run Gradle build separately from running a class (e.g. from the Gradle panel in the IDE or command line).

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. The gradle projects build successfully but when I attempt to run .jar produced or directly through IntelliJ, this error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the location of your `Main.kt` in gradle.

Example:

```kotlin
application {
    mainClassName = "com.your.package.name.MainKt"
}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to have an `application` block in a Kotlin Multiplatform project?